# NodeJS amqp: Is it possible to consume a message right after invoking the channel.close() method, before the channel closing action is completed?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a nodejs application that is using `amqp` to listen to a RabbitMQ queue from a remote server, and to consume jobs from the queue.

```
    // Connect to the rabbitMQ server and create a channel
    const connection = await amqplib.connect(RabbitMQ_URL);
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    channel.prefetch(1);

    // Assert the queue
    await channel.assertQueue(JOB_QUEUE_NAME, { durable: true });

    // start the ShutDownCounter;
    shutDownCounter.start();

    // Consume the queue
    channel.consume(
      JOB_QUEUE_NAME,
      async message => {

        const task: Task = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());

        // Process the task
        try {
          taskProgress = await processTask(task);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }

        // Acknowledge the message
        channel.ack(message);
      }
    );
```

In somewhere else, after 120 seconds of not consuming any new messages from the remote queue, I call the `channel.close()` function and then turn off the application;

Could this scenario happen:

1. at time `t = 120.001`, the `channel.close()` call is invoked; but channel is still alive;
2. at time `t = 120.003`, a new message (task) just arrive in! `channel.consume()` accepts the message. (of course such thing is doomed to happen);
3. at time `t = 120.010`, the `channel.close()` call has completed, and the channel is actually closed.
4. at time `t = 120.100`, the application is turned off, even though it is actually in the middle of processing the task.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself here...

I found that there is no need to worry at all. It is well documented in
[RabbitMQ automatic-requeueing](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#automatic-requeueing)

> When Consumers Fail or Lose Connection: Automatic Requeueing
>
> When manual acknowledgements are used, any delivery (message) that was
> not acked is automatically requeued when the channel (or connection)
> on which the delivery happened is closed. This includes TCP connection
> loss by clients, consumer application (process) failures, and
> channel-level protocol exceptions (covered below).
>
> ...
>
> Due to this behavior, consumers must be prepared to handle
> redeliveries and otherwise be implemented with idempotence in mind.
> Redeliveries will have a special boolean property, redeliver, set to
> true by RabbitMQ. For first time deliveries it will be set to false.
> Note that a consumer can receive a message that was previously
> delivered to another consumer.

I just need to make sure that manual acknowledgements are required in my app, and then even this edge case happens, the message will not be lost.